# Expression expected after this token

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, token, equals

Why is this popping up?

> Syntax error on token "+", Expression expected after       this token

```
for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 7;;) {
            data[row][col] = [row][1] + [row][2] + [row][3] + [row][4] + [row][5] + [row][6];
    }for (int col = 8;;) {
            data[row][col] = formatter.format(([row][7] / 2650) * 100);
   }
}
```

It appears on every plus sign and the equals after `data[row][col] =`.

Comment: You have an extra leading brace and you're missing a trailing brace.

Comment: This code makes no sense. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: `[row][1]` is incorrect syntax in Java.

Comment: im trying to make a total column and a percentage column in a 2d array from a bunch of grades that are in columns indexes 1-6. these are in another for loop that cycles through the rows.

Comment: row is an int, if thats the problem

Comment: added the for loop above theissue

Answer (score 0):

The `[row][col]` is an access expression for the array, so you need to specify what array you want to access on these indices. Therefore every of your statements with indices should start with `data`

```
for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 7;;) {
        data[row][col] = data[row][7] + data[row][2] + data[row][3] + data[row][4] + data[row][5] + data[row][6];
    }
    for (int col = 8;;) {
        data[row][col] = formatter.format((data[row][7] / 2650) * 100);
    }
}
```

For more information and examples see [Java Tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Also notice that you have two infinite loops, I guess the code is incomplete or the loops are redundant

```
for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    data[row][7] = data[row][1] + data[row][2] + data[row][3] + data[row][4] + data[row][5] + data[row][6];
    data[row][8] = formatter.format((data[row][7] / 2650) * 100);
}
```